# embedded character with reversed background

Tags: character, emeditor

there are 'j' character that looks like this https://su-support.tinytake.com/msc/Njc2MjcwM18xOTM3OTc0Mg causing issues when importing into db.
how to remove these at once?

i unchecked all options like this https://su-support.tinytake.com/msc/Njc2MjczMl8xOTM3OTc4Ng but it still appears

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question. Please don't link to external resources. Use the capabilities of StackOverflow, including embedding images. -- Consequently I did not follow your links. Who knows what is at that end? However, from your description, it might be end-of-line characters. These are commonly Ctrl-J for Unix-like systems, and the editor might show such control characters inverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Inverted J** is the **Line Feed (LF)** character. You can remove these by selecting the **Remove Embedded Newline Characters** command. You can find this command on the **Edit** menu - **CSV** - **Convert to**, or the **Help** menu - **Search** Commands.

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the check mark on the left to show you accept this answer.